# Using genitive and infinitive to describe characteristics

Tags: grammar-identification, genitive, reference-request, infinitive

Answering [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/11006/79), I recalled a somewhat rare construction used to express that an action is characteristic of someone.
Pekkanen's Ars Grammatica (§77.1) gives two examples:

1. *Cuiusvis hominis est errare, nullius nisi insipientis est in errore perseverare.*
2. *Adulescentis est maiores natu revereri.*<sup>1</sup>

I tried looking this up in online Latin grammars to provide a reference, but I failed to find anything.
**Can someone find an online Latin grammar that discusses this use of genitive and infinitive?**

I am not aware of a specific name for this, so it is hard to search.
Pekkanen lists it as a subclass of *genetivus possessivus*, but such classification is a somewhat arbitrary choice.

---

<sup>1</sup>
If you are puzzled by the word *natu*, see [this follow-up question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/11054/79).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Allen & Greenough §343](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/allen-greenough/Chapters/Chapter-343.html) also lists it as a type of possessive genitive, giving a few examples. Note that this use of the genitive in the predicate is used with infinitives and with clauses:

> c. An infinitive or a clause, when used as a noun, is often limited by a genitive in the predicate:—
>
> > **neque suī iūdicī [erat] discernere (B. C. 1.35)**, nor was it for his judgment to decide (nor did it belong to his judgment).
> >
> > **cûiusvīs hominis est errāre (Phil. 12.5)**, it is any man's [liability] to err.
> >
> > **negāvit mōris esse Graecōrum, ut in convīviō virōrum accumberent mulierēs (Verr. 2.1.66)**, he said it was not the custom of the Greeks for women to appear as guests (recline) at the banquets of men.
> >
> > **sed timidī est optāre necem (Ov. M. 4.115)**, but't is the coward's part to wish for death.
> >
> > **stultī erat spērāre, suādēre impudentis (Phil. 2.23)**, it was folly (the part of a fool) to hope, effrontery to urge.
> >
> > **sapientis est pauca loquī**, it is wise (the part of a wise man) to say little. [Not sapiēns (neuter) est, etc.]
>
> Note 1— This construction is regular with adjectives of the third declension instead of the neuter nominative (see the last two examples).
>
> Note 2— A derivative or possessive adjective may be used for the genitive in this construction, and must be used for the genitive of a personal pronoun:—
>
> > **mentīrī nōn est meum [not meī]**, it is not for me to lie.
> >
> > **hūmānum [for hominis] est errāre**, it is man's nature to err (to err is human).

Comment: My favorite example is A.E.I.O.U. Austriae est imperare orbi universo.

Answer (score 1):

Is this predicative genitive + esse?

"est boni imperatoris bene ducere" = "It is of a good general to lead well.";

"est digni civis patriae cogitare" = "it is of a worthy citizen to think about his country.";

"est honesti regis regere sapienter" = "It is of an honourable king to rule wisely.";

"est canis feles agitare" = "It is of a dog to chase cats."

Comment: This is precisely the thing, thanks! Did you find a place where it's discussed?

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: net: "predicative gen. + esse".

Comment: @Joons llmavirta: In the 3rd ex., have changed "honest"  to "honourable", which is more like it.