# Why ablative "natu" is used in these expressions?

Tags: syntax, grammar-identification, ablative

In the novella *Filia regis et monstrum horribile*, by Andrew Olimpi, I have read (emphasis mine):

> Fīlia prīma **nātū** est puella pulchra. Sed fīlia secunda **nātū** pulchrior est quam soror sua. [...] Fīlia
> tertia **nātū** vocatur Psȳchē.

I don't understand the usage of the ablative *nātū* in the above text. Could anyone please explain it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Natus is a noun used only in the ablative singular natu “by birth”.

Comment: Specifically that is the case for the fourth-declension noun, not the second-declension one meaning 'son' or the PPP of *nascor*, both of which are also *nātus*.

Comment: I see: I thought it was the adjective *nātus*.

Comment: @Charo It's worth checking your declension tables carefully when confused. The participle or adjective *natus* does not have a form *natu*; its ablative is *nato/nata*.

Comment: Some more details in the answer here https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/11054/the-purpose-of-natu